# Find id of selected submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have 2 input field and also 2 submit button that are hidden and i am using jquery to submit input field when **enter** is pressed,so i want to find that when enter is pressed it display selected button id i have done it in jquery bt it dont show me any id
here is example on jsfiddle

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);  
});
```

this shows me all the id but i one only selected
http://jsfiddle.net/azamalvi/kD3bx/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
$(".text").bind("keydown", function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
    if (keycode == 13) {
        // Actually display your button ID
        alert($(event.target).next().find('input').attr('id'));  
        // Then, you can submit you form :
        button = $(event.target).next().find('input');
        button.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: when i assign this id to click function then it say id.click(); is not a function can u tell me what should i do

Comment: I've edited my answer. It should work, but I can't try it yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input').click(function(eventObject) {
     var idOfButtonClicked = $(eventObject.target).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: can you help me
that i use this method var id = $(this).parent().find("input[type=submit]").attr('id');
and when i assign this id to click function then it say id.click(); is not a function can u tell me what should i do

Answer (score 1):

In case of your example code, you should use something like this, because the keydown event is raised inside a textarea

```
var id = $(this).parent().find("input[type=submit]").attr('id');
```

Comment: when i use this id and pass it to click function then it says id.click it not a function what is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:  http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmbW/

```
 $(".text").bind("keydown", function (event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
    if (keycode == 13) {

        var $id = $(this).siblings().find("input[type=submit]");
        alert($id.attr("id"));            

        ($id).click();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
```

Comment: A.V this one solve bt when one error that i dont noticed is that  (id).click(); this one does not work it gives error that id.click is not a function

Comment: yes it solve bt i can't understand what is purpose of $ to use here anyway it works

Comment: `$id` is just a variable name... (it may be just `id` or something). But what differs is `$(this).siblings().find("input[type=submit]")` fetches the element itself and then we have to trigger the `click()` function... where as `$(this).siblings().find("input[type=submit]").attr("id")` fetches the `id` of the element and triggering a `click()` event on an `id` is just invalid..